# Red and Blue Dividing Line

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers

In the grid shown below, 20 numbers are given in blue and red.

Draw a dividing line along the contours of the grid such that

A) Blue Numbers Sum to the same on both sides of the line

B) Red Numbers Sum to the same on both sides of the same line.

I.e., only one contour line can be drawn to satisfy both requirements.

[image]

A solution can look like this:

[image]

Comment: Please see what the final answer can look like

Comment: Thx..well clarified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I think this is the solution

> [image]